# Select first empty input fail

Tags: jquery

Please see my example here: [LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/Y8d4f/)

**As you can notice, the focused on input is not the first empty one. What is wrong? **

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.quick div input, .quick div textarea').live('focus', function() {
    var a = $(this).attr('id');
    var b = 'submit';

    $('.quick .focus').removeClass('focus');
    if (a == b) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('focus');
    }
});


  $('input:text[value=""]').focus(); // problematic line

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `:first`. As you are not using `:first`, it is going through every `<input type="text" value=""..` and it is stopping at the at last one. Code below will work for you

```
 $('input:text[value=""]:first').focus();
```

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/Y8d4f/34/

Comment: Alternatively, `$('input:text[value=""]').first().focus();`

Comment: @NewUser nope, it means every `<input type="text"  value=""..`, I have edited the answer too.